# Video player in mybb with mycode

Tags: html, post, html5-video, mp3, mybb

In mybb for making an MP3 player in posts with HTML5. I used below codes in mycode section.

**Regular Expression:**

```
<a href="http([s])?://(.*?)\.mp3".*?>.*?</a>
```

**Replacement:**

```
<audio src="http$1://$2.mp3" controls preload="auto" autobuffer></audio>
```

**Example:**

```
http://example.com/your.mp3
```

(No need for adding MyCode tags, just paste the URL in post content)

It uses HTML5 (no Flash or JavaScript needed).

How to add video (MP4) files in post same as MP3?

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

**Regular Expression:**

```
<a href="http([s])?://(.*?)\.mp4".*?>.*?</a>
```

**Replacement**

```
<video width="400" controls> <source src="http$1://$2.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video>
```